# How to configure Jackson to be able to deserialize special collections?

Tags: java, json, jackson

I am wondering how to configure Jackson to deserialize a serialized list of objects that were contained in 'special' collections (immutable, or the result of collected stream).

Here is my problem, for certain reasons, I need to declare de typing in jackson because I need to be able to deserialize everything and get back all my types.

```java
public static class Sink {
    private List items;

    public Sink setItems(final List items) {
        this.items = items;
        return this;
    }

    public List getItems() {
        return this.items;
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    mapper.registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());
    mapper.registerModule(new Jdk8Module());
    mapper.registerModule(new AfterburnerModule());
    mapper.enableDefaultTyping(NON_FINAL, JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY);

    String content = mapper.writeValueAsString(new Sink().setItems(List.of()));
    System.out.println(content);
    Sink result = mapper.readValue(content, Sink.class);
}
```

But this has a nasty side effect with collections.
The `content` value is:

```
{
    "@class": "api.Sink",
    "items": ["java.util.ImmutableCollections$ListN", []]
}
```

And unfortunately, the `java.util.ImmutableCollections.*` do not have default constructors (which make sense).

`Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Cannot construct instance of`java.util.ImmutableCollections$ListN`(no Creators, like default construct, exist): no default no-arguments constructor found`

I am wondering how to force jackson to deserialize those kind of object as `ArrayList` or whatever type of list.

I'd like to configure it to deserialize all sub types of list as `ArrayList` / `LinkedList` or when serializing to change the type of a collection

(java 12 / jackson 2.9.7)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can dot it using a specific Deserializer as follow for example with Mixin.

An example of the deserializer:

```
class UnmodifiableSetDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<Set> {

@Override
public Set deserialize(JsonParser jp, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
    ObjectMapper mapper = (ObjectMapper) jp.getCodec();
    JsonNode node = mapper.readTree(jp);
    Set<Object> resultSet = new HashSet<Object>();
    if (node != null) {
        if (node instanceof ArrayNode) {
            ArrayNode arrayNode = (ArrayNode) node;
            Iterator<JsonNode> nodeIterator = arrayNode.iterator();
            while (nodeIterator.hasNext()) {
                JsonNode elementNode = nodeIterator.next();
                resultSet.add(mapper.readValue(elementNode.traverse(mapper), Object.class));
            }
        } else {
            resultSet.add(mapper.readValue(node.traverse(mapper), Object.class));
        }
    }
    return Collections.unmodifiableSet(resultSet);
}
}
```

You can find a complete example in the CoreJacksont2Module of Spring security [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/tree/master/core/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/jackson2)

Comment: thanks, despite i think this is an ugly solution, it works :) you saved my day ! thx

Answer (score 1):

`2.13.0` [fixes it](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/issues/2900) ([except `Set.of()` apparently?](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/issues/2900#issuecomment-988333797)):

```java
public static class Sink {
    private List<Integer> items;

    public Sink setItems(final List<Integer> items) {
        this.items = items;
        return this;
    }

    public List<Integer> getItems() {
        return this.items;
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    ObjectMapper mapper = JsonMapper.builder()
            .findAndAddModules()
            .activateDefaultTyping(LaissezFaireSubTypeValidator.instance, EVERYTHING, JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY)
            .build();
    String content = mapper.writeValueAsString(new Sink().setItems(List.of(1)));
    System.out.println(content);
    Sink result = mapper.readValue(content, Sink.class);
}
```

Output:

```json
{
  "@class" : "api.Sink",
  "items" : [ "java.util.ImmutableCollections$List12", [ ] ]
}
```